# SP2010 designer workflow -- how to limit the user selection within a specific SP group or AD group?

Tags: designer-workflow, approval

We are building a SP designer workflow on SP2013 with SP2010 workflow platform.

Basically it is just the OOTB **Approval - SharePoint 2010** workflow (globally reusable). In OOTB approval workflow the initiator can pick anyone within Active Directory or any SharePoint group. He can pick a user or a group. He can pick himself as approver.

The only customization we need to make is to restrict workflow initiator can only pick the approver(s) within a specific group (Sharepoint group or AD security group).

I cannot find a way to workaround this part. Any idea?

**P.S:** We are using standard edition and don't have InfoPath.